# KonvaJS: Scale Image From Center

Tags: javascript, canvas, offset, konvajs

I am facing some challenges while scaling a `Konva.Image`. I want to scale the image from it's center point. Although I am able to scale it from center but I am not sure whether it is a correct way of doing this or not. Currently it is scaled from it's `top-left` corner. To scale the image from center point I am setting it's `offset` to center by using `image.setOffset()`. But I don't know why it is moving the image. I am doing this:

```
  //setting the offset to center
  //but don't know why it's moving the image.
  yoda.setOffset({
    x: yoda.width() / 2,
    y: yoda.height() / 2
  });
  // setting it's position back to original
  // position but don't know why I need to
  // adding the offset values
  yoda.position({
    x: 50 + yoda.width() / 2,
    y: 50 + yoda.height() / 2
  });
```

To scale the image I am doing this:

```
 yoda.scale({
          x: 0.5,
          y: 0.5
        });
        layer.draw();
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same? Here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tYKdxi?p=preview) to play.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour of `Konva` nodes. You have to use `offset` and `{x,y}` properties together.

You can avoid using `offset`, but in that case, you will have to change `{x,y}` while scaling.

Comment: Thanks lavrton... Seems like I need to learn the concept of offset first. Do you have any link which explains it thoroughly?

Comment: I'm also having trouble trying to set up the offset to the center and then using `scaleX()` and `scaleY()`. I've tried and tried. I just can't get it working.